# exec causes the heap and stack and other parts of the memory space of the program re-initialized

Tags: c

I am reading the [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces* book](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/cpu-api.pdf), Chapter 5.

It says:

> The `fork()` system call is strange; its partner in crime, `exec()`, is
> not so normal either. What it does: given the name of an executable
> (e.g., wc), and some arguments (e.g., p3.c), it loads code (and static
> data) from that executable and overwrites its current code segment
> (and current static data) with it; **the heap and stack and other parts
> of the memory space of the program are re-initialized**.

Then I have a question with this sample code in this chapter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc = fork();
    if (rc < 0) {
        // fork failed; exit
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (rc == 0) {
    // child: redirect standard output to a file
    close(STDOUT_FILENO); 
    open("./p4.output", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);

    // now exec "wc"...
        char *myargs[3];
        myargs[0] = strdup("wc");   // program: "wc" (word count)
        myargs[1] = strdup("p4.c"); // argument: file to count
        myargs[2] = NULL;           // marks end of array
        execvp(myargs[0], myargs);  // runs word count
    } else {
        // parent goes down this path (original process)
        int wc = wait(NULL);
    assert(wc >= 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

According to `man strdup`, `margs[0]` and `margs[1]` are created with `malloc` on the heap. So when `execvp` **reinitialize** the heap and stack the child's memory space, won't they be cleared or destroyed so as a result using `margs[0]` and `margs[1]` would be undefined behaviour?

Comment: uh, except no, my comment didn't make any sense. Comment deleted. Either way, it's obviously safe to do otherwise there would be no safe way to pass params to `exec`. I'm guessing the params are stored in OS structures, and they're fetched by the loader from the OS to pass to its `main`.

Answer (score 1):

The newly created process makes a copy of the arguments from the `myargs` array before the old process memory is zapped, precisely so there is no problem with memory accesses.

The POSIX specification for [`excevp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/excevp.html) et al says:

> The arguments specified by a program with one of the exec functions shall be passed on to the new process image in the corresponding `main()` arguments.

That page specifies a lot of other key behaviours of the `exec()` family of functions.  You'll probably find that the Linux equivalent page specifies even more things that are affected (or not affected) by the `exec()` family of functions.

Note that if a function from the `exec()` family succeeds, it does not return.  If it returns, it failed.  There's no need to check the return value (because it will always be -1).  But there is usually a need to report that the execution failed and most often, a process exits with a non-zero status after a failed `exec()`.